# Underscore _.contains method always failed inside mongoose promise query

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io, underscore.js, promise

Hi im using mongoose query inside socket.io event, so far so good. I want to check if a user is a member to a private room then fetch messages. So i use underscore method _.contains() but is always return false. I don't know what wrong with the code cuz logging both list and checked item it should return true

```
socket.on('add user', function (data) {
        var username = data.username;
        var userId = data.userId;
        var currentroom = data.room ? data.room : '559c02cfd2ad52cc276b7491';

        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        socket.userid = userId;

        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        ++numUsers;
        socket.emit('login', {
            numUsers: numUsers
        });

        var room = new roomModel();
        return room.getRoomParticipants(currentroom)
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log('checking room');
            console.log(res);
            if (!res) {
                throw new Error('Couldn\'t get room participants!');
            }

            res = res[0];
            var participants = res.participants;
            return participants;
        })
        .then(function(participants) {
            if (!_.contains(participants, socket.userid)) {
                console.log('have failed');
                return null;
            }

            _.each(participants, function(item) {
                var user = new userModel();
                user.getById(item)
                .then(function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        rommates[res._id] = res;
                    }
                })
            });
            return roommates;
        })
        .then(function(participants) {
            var message = new messageModel();
            message.roomMessages(currentroom, msgLimit)
            .then(function(res) {
                _.each(res, function(item) {
                    var data = {};
                    var user = rommates[res._id];
                    data.username = user.username;
                    data.message = item.msg;
                    data.time = item.created_at;
                    socket.emit('new message', data);
                });
            });

        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
            logger.debug(err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Well, if `_.contains(participants, socket.userid)` returns `false`, it cannot really be in the list? Could you perhaps have mixed data types?

Comment: @DanielB thx for pointing it! Didn't know about mixed type... From console i got something like from `list ["a", "B"]` and var just  `a`

Comment: even if i use `_.flatten()` got the same issue http://underscorejs.org/#flatten

Comment: got object for list and string for the var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing

```
if (!_.contains(participants, socket.userid)) {
   return null;
}
```

with

```
var participants = _.object(res.participants);
    var allowed = _.find(res.participants, function(item) {
    return item == socket.userid;
});
if (!allowed) {
   throw new Error('User ' + socket.userid + ' is not allowed to room ' + currentroom);
}
```